# How to prevent form DDoS attack

Tags: networking

Here i have problem in my Ubuntu server its got attacked by some hackers last week so now i downed the server so any one please help me how to prevent from D Dos attack in my Ubuntu server.Thanks in Advance any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Here is a good article that you can look at http://linuxgazette.net/126/cherian.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install and configure fail2ban, install and configure ninja, turn off ntp server component, install and configure a firewall, increase password complexity, put high level services into their own container, and try to find some kind of DDos warning software.

Edit: Also, see [this guide](http://hexwiki.com/wiki/Security_%28Wheezy%29). It is for Debian Wheezy, but should work well for Ubuntu as well.